# Idioms meaning to do something at great cost

Tags: idioms, expressions

What I'm looking for isn't quite the same as a Pyrrhic victory, as the action isn't necessarily done to obtain victory. Rather, it is any action that will ultimately result in the person taking said action to pay great (preferably terrible) cost either along the way or afterward, whether or not they realize it in advance.

Comment: Please provide an example of such an action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old timey, but carries the meaning you seek:

> Then, as the story progresses, to the **supreme sacrificial effort** of Jeanie in behalf of her erring sister's life...

[Masters of the English Novel](http://books.google.com/books?id=4UEqAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA135&lpg=PA135&dq=%22supreme%20sacrificial%20effort%22&source=bl&ots=jFw0Qk9uMB&sig=htOq6GgHv7VOReBJqm8_4rBNCVo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GvYDUdKqOu_E2QXJv4FQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22supreme%20sacrificial%20effort%22&f=false)

Answer (score 4):

You could try [***to pay dearly***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/pay-dearly)

> to suffer a lot as a result of a particular action or event
>   *If you refuse to cooperate with us, you will pay dearly for it.*
>
> [***dear***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dearly) :  *At a high cost*

Comment: Simply 'pay a terrible price.' It's idiomatic (accepted and well-known) but isn't a nice opaque type of idiom.